# Single table or multiples tables (multiple company database)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have to create a database for multiple companies, I have 2 options

1. A single `products` table, with a `company_id` field to differentiate
2. One table per company

   `products_company1`
   `products_company2`
   `products_company3`

**Important**:

- Data stored of each client will be updated every 1 hour
- Each company has 2000 - 3000 records, and 15 company will be stored approx.
- Products table is an example, each company has more tables.

I did a search, but did not find information about multiple tables, only multiple databases (I don't think multiple databases its a good option for me)

Comment: Go with option 1!!!

Comment: Never, ever, go with option 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want option 1 under almost all circumstances.  Here are some reasons:

1. Relational databases are optimized to work on large tables, not on large numbers of tables.
2. Maintaining foreign key relationships is very challenging.
3. Maintenance many tables (say by adding a column or changing a data type) is a nightmare compared to maintaining one table.
4. Answering a simple question such as "how many companies have product X" is a nightmare.

There are no doubt other reasons as well.  These come to mind.

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on your requirements.

1. Shared table will be simplest and most flexible, especially if the same product can exist for multiple companies and you want a query to return of all that product's records across all companies.
2. Different tables can make it simpler to encrypt data with company provided keys (assuming companies are your paying customers) if your database has support for different encryptions per-table and not just per-database.
3. Different tables mean manual updates/deletions for a product record can't accidently touch products of other companies - it's much more likely to forget a "where company = ..." then to run your command manually on wrong table.
4. Shared table means you can batch insert rows from multiple companies in a single transaction which in some scenarios can make your performance more scalable, though might created undesired coupling (as I said - depends on your requirements).

There are probably more things to consider, above are what I thought of at the moment. Note that the total amounts of rows you expect should be simple enough to handle in a single table for any mature SQL database.